# Get values of object properties as type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to achieve the below?

```
const x = {
  a: { 
    prop: 'something',
  },
  b: {
    prop: 'another',
  }
}

// desired output
['something', 'another']
```

Comment: Your question title says "as type" - are you trying to construct this as a tuple type? In a specific order?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isnt very clear, but do you mean to do this?

```
const x = {
  a: {
    prop: "something",
  },
  b: {
    prop: "another",
  },
};

const z = Object.keys(x).map((item) => x[item].prop);
console.log(z);
// [ 'something', 'another' ]
```

Comment: Or even more compact: `Object.values(x).map(item => item.prop)`